# how to use redux or any other state management libraries with react using cdn

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a corporate laptop and I can't install npm in that, that's why I have been using react with cdn. I'm facing some problems with updating states in my project so I decided to use a state management library, I did find the cdn link but I can't find any tutorial or materials on how to use the library using a cdn. I'm new to the js ecosystem and really need some pointers on the starting direction. For eg:
`import {observable} from 'mobx-react'`
doesn't work with cdn.
It gives the error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

add the **cdn** script in the `head` tag  of  `index.html` to make it work  :

to use **mobx** `v 6.6.2`    :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobx/6.6.2/mobx.umd.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-eIWf4utGE5IvRknZTPJQurSa6SKD8gT4B430UugX3afhpnjNqQ0fAY6/1rfPNro+8pwVd3bWaMTovLMoIgYWEw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

for other versions you can see the  [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mobx) doc